unable to Angular 18 with webpack-bundle-analyzer
I'm building my Angular 18 application for bundle analysis:
ng build -stats-json

The resulting stats.json has 38K lines.
Then I attempt to analyze using:
webpack-bundle-analyzer <path-to-json-file>

which gives me an error:
Could't analyze webpack bundle:
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')


would you be using esbuild instead of webpack?

Yep, just learned about esbuild vs webpack

You're using the application builder which doesn't rely on webpack but on esbuild.
For esbuild, you should you this analyzer: https://esbuild.github.io/analyze/
Contrary to the webpack solution, there is dedicated package for that yet, this is only accessible via the webpage. See the dedicated issue on that topic.

Do you mean this one "esbuild-visualizer": "^0.6.0"? I tried installing it but running it just does nothing, and shows no errors. Can you update your answer with more steps that worked for you?

There is no dedicated package for that atm.
See this dedicated issue on GitHub: https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2847
